# Using ESP 32 for 7 segment display

Tags: c++, esp32, seven-segment-display

The `void one()` was not displaying in 7 segments. What might be the problem?

```
int pinout[] = {23,22,21,19,18,5,4};
int zeroseg[] = {23,22,21,19,18,4};
int oneseg[] = {22,21,19,18,4,23};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
    pinMode(pinout[i], OUTPUT);
}

void d() {
  delay(1000);
}

void zero() {
  for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    digitalWrite(zeroseg[i], HIGH);
}

void one() {
  for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
    digitalWrite(oneseg[i], HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  zero();
  d();
  one();
  d();
}
```

I try using array and `for` loop but it's not displaying.

Comment: You do not only have to turn on the segments for the "1" but you have to turn off all other segments that are still on from the "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using digitalWrite(zeroseg[i], HIGH); -- HIGH
and here as well digitalWrite(zeroseg[i], HIGH); -- HIGH

You are never using LOW.
Does all the segments stay ON or all of them stay OFF

Regards